# How to order relationships data and load subrelated data from loaded relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have custom query where I get user `jobs` and after, load `jobs` relationships

**Code**

```
$jobs = $user->jobs->load('views', 'reacts', 'phoneClicks');
```

This code work successfully. But when I tried order `jobs` by date Laravel return me error

**Code**

```
$jobs = $user->jobs->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->load('views', 'reacts', 'phoneClicks');
```

**Error**

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not
>   exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it like this

```
$jobs = $user->jobs()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->with('views', 'reacts', 'phoneClicks')->get();
```